# r.string error "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android

I just opened an older android app project and all of a sudden numerous R.string._var_Name errors were found.  If I add "import android.R" then the _var_name becomes an issue saying "cannot be resolved or is not a field".  The translation is in /res/values/strings.xml .  Any ideas why the error exists?

Comment: Is your problem resolved by answer of Kurtis Nusbaum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case import android.R was usually the problem. I then removed it and build again (eclipse) and than it worked. Cleaning the project often helps too.

Comment: That didn't do the trick.  When I worked on it last I had no problems.  I have since upgraded Motodev and now opening the project I have the problem.

Comment: I also delete the gen files and did a rebuild.

Answer (score 14):

If your class files are not in your root package, you'll need to import them at the top of your file like this:

```
your.package.name.R
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project>Properties>Builders` and see if 'Android Resource Manager' is checked.
Or go to Project and do 'Clean' to rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem when modify the samples of vuforia. I resolved that adding the `string name=...` necessary in the file `strings.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

add `import com.example.android.yourprojectname.R` to your imports at the top of the file in which the error is occurring in, replace yourprojectname with your project/app name. This should resolve it.