# Why does my code not work?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have the following code to get information from a rating bar and put it into a TextView but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView ratingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ratingText);
    RatingBar rating=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating);
    rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((OnRatingBarChangeListener) this);

}

public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,float rating, boolean fromUser){
    ratingText.setText(""+this.rating.getRating()); 
}
```

At the second last line of code it is giving me the following error: "rating cannot be resolved or is not a field" and "ratingText cannot be resolved". I am wondering why I am getting these errors and how to fix them. Thanks.

Comment: this could be an issue with your R variable. What are you using to edit and compile this?

Comment: pick an answer @MostafaSaadat

Comment: @cacho None of them worked in the end, I just gave up :(

Comment: ok, then you could try to explain again what is your problem. Or start a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

a-) I think your problem is that you need that your class `MainActivity` implements `OnRatingBarChangeListener`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener {

}
```

b-) Another possible error is that you need to make sure that you do NOT have this in your imports:

```
import android.R;
```

but:

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

c-) Declare the `TextView ratingText` and the `RatingBar rating` outside of the method, as an attribute of the class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: OK, let me update my answer with other possible errors @MostafaSaadat

Comment: I declared the "ratingText" and "rating" outside of the method and it worked, but when I call this line of code "rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((OnRatingBarChangeListener) this);", it doesn't send that information down to the "rating" on this line "ratingText.setText(""+this.rating.getRating());"

Comment: that is fine, because the method 'onRatingChanged()' will only be called when the rating changes.

Comment: Alright, but for some reason when I try to run the app it just gives me an error and closes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29072/discussion-between-mostafa-saadat-and-cacho)

Comment: @MostafaSaadat pick one of the answers as the Accepted Answer if they helped you.....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this for a solution.

[r.string error "cannot be resolved or is not a field"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933190/r-string-error-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

Main idea is to make sure your R reference is correct, and try by deleting the gen files and rebuild the project.

EDIT::
This was incorrect the problem was stated in another answer. by @Marv

Answer (score 0):

It is because you create your `ratingText` and `rating` in the `onCreate` method. This means they are only available inside this method.

Try to do something like this:

```
private TextView ratingText = null;
private RatingBar rating = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ratingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ratingText);
    rating=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating);
    rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((OnRatingBarChangeListener) this);

}
```

This way they are available in the entire class and you can use them in `onRatingChanged`.

Comment: This helped, thanks; the "ratingText" and "rating" are available in the onRatingChanged method now but the onRatingChanged method doesn't get the "rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((OnRatingBarChangeListener) this);" because it is in the OnCreate method. I don't know if what I wrote makes sense.

Comment: @MostafaSaadat Try adding `implements OnRatingBarChangeListener` to the class.

Comment: @MostafaSaadat Okay. What exactly is not working the way you want it to? And what happens? Does the method not get invoked when you change the rating bar?

Comment: The last line "ratingText.setText(""+this.rating.getRating())" isn't able to get the rating from when I called ""rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((OnRatingBarChangeListener) this);

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener{

    TextView ratingText;
    RatingBar rating;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);

        ratingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_aaa);
        rating=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((OnRatingBarChangeListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
        boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ratingText.setText(""+this.rating.getRating());
    }

}
```